# chatterbot.logic.SpecificResponseAdapter is not working

Tags: python-3.x, chatterbot

I want to develop my own custom chatbot but I get some issue during the development, I want to use Specific Response Adapter in `chatterbot`. There is a sample of code.

```
from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer
bot = ChatBot('Mybot',
storage_adapter='chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter',
logic_adapters=[{'import_path': 'chatterbot.logic.SpecificResponseAdapter',
               'input_text': 'Help me!',
                'output_text': 'Ok'
                        }]) # Crate Chatbot
trainer = ListTrainer(bot)
text = open('/content/drive/My Drive/Chatbot/Data/data.txt').readlines()
trainer.train(text)

while True:
   request = input("Your: ")
   response = bot.get_response(request)
   print("bot:",response)
```

This is the output:

```
 Your: Help me!
 bot: I am sorry, but I do not understand.
 Your: 'Help me!'
 bot: I am sorry, but I do not understand.
```

please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Can you tell us what your expected outcome is and how that's different from what is happening currently?

Comment: expected answer must be 'OK'